# How can I put off everything in my code until a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, button, wait

Working on a JavaScript program, and the first thing that happens when run is asking the user whether they want to enter something using prompt()s, or using a textarea. The textarea option comes with a clickable button element to press once the user has entered everything they want into the textarea.
If this option is chosen, I want the rest of my program to not run until this button is clicked, and the user is confirming that they are finished with their input. Currently I have the button code within the selection part (where the user has chosen to use a textarea), as below:

```
if (trimmedResponse == 'manual') { 
  ... (irrelevant code)
} else { //if paste is chosen
  var createArray = function(howMany){
    var pasteInput = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    var makingArray = [];
    document.body.appendChild(pasteInput);
    pasteInput.rows = howMany;
    let done = document.createElement("button");
    done.innerHTML = 'Enter terms';
    done.onclick = function(){
      for (var j = 0; j < howMany; j++){
        makingArray[j] = String((pasteInput.value).replace(/ /g,'').split('-')).split('\n');
      }
      pasteInput.style.display = 'none';
      done.style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.body.appendChild(done);
    return makingArray;
  }

  termArray = window.createArray(numOfTerms); //getting a variable holding the array from the prior function, to access later
}
```

The rest of the script.js file is made up of the regular subroutines - preload, setup, draw, and some initialisation and other small methods in the open scope before preload(), as below in a greatly reduced format:

```
let BG;
let translateEdit = document.createElement("button");
translateEdit.innerHTML = "Edit a translation";
translateEdit.style.position = 'absolute';
translateEdit.style.left = '50px';
translateEdit.style.top = '130px';
let list = "";
translateEdit.onclick = function () {
    this.blur();
    do {
      replaceChoice = prompt("Which translation do you want to edit? (1-"+numOfTerms+") \n"+list+" \nOr enter any letter to leave this screen.");
    } while (replaceChoice < 1 || replaceChoice > termArray.length)
    termArray[replaceChoice-1][1] = prompt("What is the new translation for the term "+termArray[replaceChoice-1][0]+"?");
    list = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfTerms ; i++){
        list += ((i+1)+". ["+termArray[i][0] + "]  -  [" + termArray[i][1] + "]\n") //adds each term and translation in a user-friendly / clear display to the list variable for later display
    }
    alert("The term list currently looks as follows: \n"+list);
};
document.body.appendChild(translateEdit);
let temp1;
let temp2;
let temp3;
var performanceDisplay = "";

function preload() { //function loading image from file into variable
    Helvetica = loadFont('Helvetica-Bold.ttf');
    BG = loadImage('images/background.png');
}

function setup() { //function to create display/background using image file and dimensions and instantiate objects (character,terms,counters) as well as slider and icon to be displayed for it
    alert("Below are the terms you have entered: \n" + list + "If any of the above are incorrect, use the edit buttons on the next screen to adjust terms or translations.");
    speakericon = loadImage('images/speaker.png');
    createCanvas(width, height);
  ... (further code in setup())
}

function draw() { //make background + objects visible on screen, allow them to act as they must, creating new terms when necessary, calling functions in class files such as player movement (calls all functions in classes throughout function) - all run every tick
        image(BG, 0, 0, width, height); //set the display to the background image from BG variable in preload()
 ... (further code in draw())
}
```

In essence, I need to stop everything else from running until the button 'done' is clicked, and would appreciate any help with anything to achieve this.

Comment: Run the code from inside the "click" handler on the button.

Comment: Should I put absolutely everything after into the 'onclick' function? Would I still be able to use variables defined and initialised here in other files/class functions?